# Рекурсивный поиск значения и удаление строк до и после него в bash

Tags: bash, shell

Есть набор папок с несколькими xml внутри

xml содержит блоки, типа

```
<group>
 <groupName>Worker</groupName>
 <groupCount>15</groupCount>
 <groupStatus>1</groupStatus>
</group>
<group>
 <groupName>Driver</groupName>
 <groupCount>3</groupCount>
 <groupStatus>1</groupStatus>
</group>
<group>
 <groupName>Thief</groupName>
 <groupCount>13</groupCount>
 <groupStatus>1</groupStatus>
</group>
```

Надо удалить целиком блок

```
<group>
...
</group>
```

во всех xml во всех папках, где groupName=Thief

Поиск из верхней папки

```
grep -r -A 3 -B 1 "groupName>Thief<"
```

или

```
cat *.xml | grep -ir -A 3 -B 1 "groupName>Thief<"
```

Возвращает имена файлов и нужные блоки, но как их удалить из файлов?

Comment: Парсить xml регулярками на баше - та еще затея. Используйте лучше какой-нибудь нормальный язык или хотя бы готовую утилиту, понимающую xpath.

Comment: Помимо того, что сказал @user7860670, и за что я голосую +100500, у вас ещё _useless use of cat_.